# Is it possible to tell which of my own questions, answers and comments were flagged?

Tags: discussion, flags

It might be instructive or otherwise enlightening to know which of my questions, answers and possibly comments had been flagged by someone in the community.  I'll try to explain why.

First think of question & answer *votes* on the main site.  A up or down vote on the main site is often used to express when someone agrees or disagrees with *what* the person said.  A flag on the other hand is often used to express disagreement with *how* the person said it.  In a similar way that it can be instructive to know the distribution of up/down votes on a particular question or answer (if you have enough rep), it might also be instructive to to know when something I've said was flagged.

Obviously I'm not asking if I can know *who* flagged me -- that would go against the principle of anonymous voting & flagging.

I'm also not talking about close votes.  That is a completely different mechanism, and if we have enough rep we can already see how many votes to close a question has accumulated.  The accumulation of these votes to close can be used as a signal to the OP that a question is in need of clarification or amendment, and votes to reopen is a signal that the edits they are making are on the right path.

Is it possible to know if my comments, answers or questions were flagged; even if no action were taken?

Comment: Look at the issues that guessing who downvoted your question sometimes causes. I think you'll end up with the same problems.... "why u flag my answer, I am downvoting all your posts"

Comment: I can't see any good coming from this.  If there is a real problem with your post then some action will be taken from the flag, such as deletion, editing, closing (if it's a question), etc.  You can potentially have a useful response to *that*, which is different from the flag that may or may not have lead to it.

Comment: @psubsee2003:  I would posit that's not a real problem.  The auto-refunder would fix the serial downvoting.  Second I'm guessing it would be as difficult to guess who flagged as who downvoted, and I don't see the problems you describe very often in the form of flamewars.  In addition, in order to mitigate the little flamewars, it could be a 10K privelidge.

Comment: @Servy:  I don't know, I think it has the potential to be useful in a similar way as being able to see that a question or answer was downvoted.  It could help some get some kind of feedback that thier contributions could be improved.

Comment: @JohnDibling you are assuming 10Kers would play by the rules.  And yes the serial voting would (probably get reversed), but it is the other messes that is left for the mods (like long comment chains) and the inevitable mod flags if all of the votes don't get reversed.  Why invite that kind of trouble.

Comment: @JohnDibling If the flag isn't acted on, then there is clearly nothing to respond to.  If the flag *is* acted on, then you have that action to respond to, not the flag.  In no situation is knowing about the flag giving you feedback you wouldn't have already gotten.

Comment: @JohnDibling also, sometimes flags are not relevant to the post, but are for another reason, some of which are not even about the author, and may contain information that the author of the post does not need to know.

Comment: @psubsee2003:  I'm assuming that relative to day-1 users, 10Kers are more likely to play by the rules, yes.

Comment: @Servy Don't really agree. You might as well argue that there's no value to seeing individual downvotes on your posts because being able to see the final score is enough, and notifying you that you've been downvoted just encourages downvote wars. But it's not just the final result that matters in either case; knowing that *somebody* thought there was a problem with your post - even if it's not the majority opinion - is potentially useful feedback.

Comment: @JohnDibling more likely to play by the rules, yes, and they **should** know better, but doesn't mean they play nice with others when they feel they've been wrong in some fashion.

Comment: @MarkAmery The *purpose* of votes is to provide feedback to the author and other readers.  That is not the purpose of flags; their goal is not to provide feedback, their goal is to communicate with moderators because there is some problem so serious *it is beyond the capability of the community to resolve on its own*.

Comment: @Servy Perhaps we're interpreting the question here differently; I'm interpreting a 'flag' as anything that can be done from the flag dialog (i.e. primarily the casting of close votes), whereas you seem to be interpreting it only as only diamond moderator flags. Your last point doesn't really apply to close votes.

Comment: @Servy:  Look at it from a different perspective.  The purpose of votes is (largely) to express agreement or disagreement with *what* the person said.  The purpose of flags is often to express disagreement with *how* the person said it.  The latter is visible only to mods.  Can it not be useful to users to have at least some redacted version of this information as well?

Comment: @MarkAmery There is already a privilege to see votes to close on your own questions, so I fail to see a need for this.

Comment: @AlienArrays:  Yes you can see how many votes to close there are.  I'm not sure I see your point.

Comment: [This data query doesn't answer your question completely](http://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/159055?UserId=241536) but it shows which posts have a flag at the moment of the datadump. I checked with a mod that a flag here is indeed a flag in the mod tools. This are however ALL flags including the once like 'too much comments'. The value of this query seems low and not suitable for your goal.

Comment: @rene: Interesting query!  See this is already helpful.  I had completely forgotten about one of those questions, but I think I had better take a closer look at that.

Comment: @rene:  Is that query telling me that my answer on the "C# Performance" question has 3 (!) flags in the mod queue *right now*?

Comment: The whole point I'm trying to convey in my answer is that when a question/ answer is flagworthy you will know (somehow) from the attitude of SO users, that's why I see it's somehow meaningless. There are many ways to convey that people disagree with *how* you posted your question.

Comment: @JohnDibling based on the data yes, I assume it has at least 'too many comments', maybe 'excessively long'  and... I dunno 'not an answer'? There is simply not enough data in the sede to answer that. You can contact a mod if you really want to sort that out.

Answer (score 6):

I don't believe so, not in your profile anyway.

You only see the *results* (if any) of a flagging operation (such as deletion or closing).  Moderators can see flagging information in the mod queues, but those queues also identify the flagger (except for SPAM and OFFENSIVE flags), so that information would have to be redacted, if we were to show it to users.

A flag that is dismissed without moderator action being taken is not relevant.

Comment: Spam/offensive shows that these days.